# How to connect MongoDB version 1.1.7 using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

Previously I was using mongo 1.4 version in PHP. But now I have upgraded to MongoDB 1.1.7. So, I am using following code to connect with mongoDB.

```
  $mongo = new MongoClient();
```

But I am getting following error:

```
  Class 'MongoClient' not found
```

Please suggest me to reslove this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you meant you upgraded from 1.1.7 to 1.4?

According to PHP.net, `MongoClient` is deprecated in versions past 1.3.0.  Use `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php

Comment: i tried this and connected with mongodb but when i connect to database got error "Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$database_name"

Comment: Can you suggest how to connect with database and collection

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing the code that has the problem.  This page has several examples of how to connect:  http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

Comment: Thanks for reply but i sloved this problem